# jQuery noconflict not working?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I seem to be having problems with this and I cannot seem to figure out which component is causing it even after lot's of testing.

So what I did was use the

```
jQuery.noConflict();  
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
   jQuery("a").click(function() {  
     alert("Hello world!");  
   });  
 });
```

I also replaced all $ with 'jQuery".
However while the "$ is not a function" errors disappeared, a lot of the code still doesn't work.

Here is one working example that doesn't work on the site:
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/Q3YpU/3/

[When you look at my site, the 'active' portion doesn't seem to work even though it's the same code](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/)

Link to Js file:
[Link](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/js/slide-buttons.js)

And finally, this whole portion of the code doesn't work:

```
jQuery('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
jQuery("#myTable").tablesorter({  
    headers: {  
        0: { 
            sorter: false 
        }, 
        8: { 
            sorter: false 
        } 
    },
        widgets: ['zebra']


});
```

While it's not throwing out any errors, the custom scrollbar doesn't work and neither does the table-sorter plugin.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Your plugins arent working because they themselves also use the `$`. So a conflict exists and they don't execute. You can either replace those with `jQuery` or, inside the plugin file, add `jQuery.noConflict();`</s>

Whenever jQuery code is called it needs to execute the `noConflict()` function. You can not store this function in a variable like: `$js`. Try using `js` instead.

Comment: Thanks Joey, I will try this and post the results :)!

Comment: Also before I forget, [if you look into this file](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js), notice how the only $ is placed. Can I also replace that with `jQuery` ?

Comment: No, if i'm not mistaken you can leave that one. I think the problem lies in the table sorter plugin, which makes heavy use of the `$` as a variable and/or function

Comment: Hmmm, do you think that it might be better for me to rather just kill whatever plugin is causing this error? The scrollpane doesn't work even though it uses only 1 $ which I replaced, and I also replaced all of the $ on the table sorter which makes me think that it might be easier to just find the source of the problem and replace it with something else.

Comment: What other JS libraries are you using besides jQuery?

Comment: Also, on the bottom of your index page youre also doing: `var $js = jQuery.noConflict();` when after you still use `$`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. I find this extremely weird because I have now excluded most of the files in the main page: [See the source now](http://www.nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/) and look at this standalone file that loads the same libraries as [those that are still active on the main page](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/all-events2.html). As far as I know I'm not using anything else other than the standard Jquery 1.6. I'm not even using Jquery UI.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the $js. I changed that, however I still think there's a problem elsewhere and I'm vigorously stripping the site to see what it is. In the normal state, all code works except the 'today, tomorrow, some other day' buttons, the custom scrollbar and the table. They do work in all-events2.html

Comment: I updated my answer. If youre only using jQuery there shouldnt be a reason at all to call `noConflict()`. Try changing `$js` into `js`. I believe using  `$` for jQuery after calling `noConflict()`, fires off some errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4561/discussion-between-joey-van-ommen-and-pufamuf)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Without you I wouldn't have gotten there. The issue was that (I didn't mention) the content was loaded dynamically, and the code that executed the scrollbar and tablesorter was executed before the content was loaded in. So I took that code and put it into all-events.html and it works now! Thanks!